# YOLOv3 training issues on the GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, yolo

I have a problem with YOLOv3 (keras) training on the GPU.

Operating System: Windows 11 Pro.
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070
Python: 3.7.16
wonders: 10.0.130
cudnn: 7.6.5
tensorflow: 1.15.0
tensorflow-gpu: 1.15.0
keras: 2.2.4

After running the training script provided in the Jupyter notebook: https://github.com/roboflow/keras-yolo3/blob/master/Tutorial.ipynb, it is not possible to train using the GPU due to an error: 'failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED.'

The full output is below:

```
Create YOLOv3 model with 9 anchors and 47 classes.
C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py:1140: UserWarning: Skipping loading of weights for layer conv2d_59 due to mismatch in shape ((1, 1, 1024, 156) vs (255, 1024, 1, 1)).
weight_values[i].shape))
C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py:1140: UserWarning: Skipping loading of weights for layer conv2d_59 due to mismatch in shape ((156,) vs (255,)).
weight_values[i].shape))
C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py:1140: UserWarning: Skipping loading of weights for layer conv2d_67 due to mismatch in shape ((1, 1, 512, 156) vs (255, 512, 1, 1)).
weight_values[i].shape))
C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py:1140: UserWarning: Skipping loading of weights for layer conv2d_67 due to mismatch in shape ((156,) vs (255,)).
weight_values[i].shape))
C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py:1140: UserWarning: Skipping loading of weights for layer conv2d_75 due to mismatch in shape ((1, 1, 256, 156) vs (255, 256, 1, 1)).
weight_values[i].shape))
C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py:1140: UserWarning: Skipping loading of weights for layer conv2d_75 due to mismatch in shape ((156,) vs (255,)).
weight_values[i].shape))
Load weights model_data/yolo.h5.
Freeze the first 249 layers of total 252 layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:1521: The name tf.log is deprecated. Please use tf.math.log instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3080: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py:790: The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.

Train on 1344 samples, val on 335 samples, with batch size 2.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:986: The name tf.assign_add is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign_add instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:973: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:850: The name tf.summary.merge_all is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.merge_all instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:853: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.

Epoch 1/250
2023-11-19 18:02:57.390440: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] shape_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
2023-11-19 18:02:57.422375: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] remapper failed: Invalid argument: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
2023-11-19 18:02:57.536783: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] layout failed: Invalid argument: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
2023-11-19 18:02:57.642200: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] shape_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
2023-11-19 18:02:57.667959: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] remapper failed: Invalid argument: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
2023-11-19 18:02:57.874195: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2023-11-19 18:04:54.112161: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2023-11-19 18:04:54.211404: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2023-11-19 18:05:31.922039: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/kk/kkFiles/keras-yolo3/train.py", line 206, in <module>
_main()
File "c:/Users/kk/kkFiles/keras-yolo3/train.py", line 75, in _main
callbacks=[logging, checkpoint])
File "C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
class_weight=class_weight)
File "C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1217, in train_on_batch
outputs = self.train_function(ins)
File "C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
return self._call(inputs)
File "C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
File "C:\Users\kk\.conda\envs\kk_Environment\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1472, in __call__
run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Internal: Blas SGEMM launch failed : m=86528, n=32, k=64
[[{{node conv2d_3/convolution}}]]
[[loss/add_74/_2891]]
(1) Internal: Blas SGEMM launch failed : m=86528, n=32, k=64
[[{{node conv2d_3/convolution}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? I tried to use these commands, but it didn't help:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Comment: Does it train correctly on CPU?

Comment: Yes, on CPU it works fine.